# Open a quick link in the same tab

Tags: sharepoint-online

I added a quick link to a library using URL, but when i click on the link, it opens the library in a new tab. Is there a way to make the quick links work in the same tab?

Comment: Would  it be possible for you to provide a screenshot. And highlight where the link is? It will be easier from there to provide a ideal response.

Comment: The quick link is in a page. I wanted to add a link in that page to open a library

Answer (score 1):

Okay. So if the link is on a page, edit the page, and click on the text supporting the link. That will bring up the context menu for hyperlinks. From there, you should see the option for open in a new tab. Make sure it is not selected. See my screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also check the hyperlink via Browser Developer Tool, if in the hyperlink there is target="_blank", then it will open in the new tab:
[image]

Uncheck the "Open in the new tab" option, it will open in the same tab.